# Removing a substring from a string, repeatedly

Tags: java, string, algorithm, replace, substring

**Problem:**
Remove the substring `t` from a string `s`, repeatedly and print the number of steps involved to do the same.

**Explanation/Working:**

> **For Example:**  `t = ab`, `s = aabb`. In the first step, we check if `t` is
>   contained within `s`. Here, `t` is contained in the middle i.e. `a(ab)b`.
>   So, we will remove it and the resultant will be `ab` and increment the
>   `count` value by 1. We again check if `t` is contained within `s`. Now, `t` is
>   equal to `s` i.e. `(ab)`. So, we remove that from `s` and increment the
>   `count`. So, since `t` is no more contained in `s`, we stop and print the
>   `count` value, which is 2 in this case.

**So, here's what I have tried:**

1. ***Code 1:***

   ```
   static int maxMoves(String s, String t) {
       int count = 0,i;

       while(true)
       {
           if(s.contains(t))
           {
               i = s.indexOf(t);
               s = s.substring(0,i) + s.substring(i + t.length());
           }
           else break;

           ++count;
       }

       return count;
   }
   ```

   I am just able to pass 9/14 test cases on Hackerrank, due to some reason (I am getting *"Wrong Answer"* for rest of the cases). After a while, I found out that there is something called `replace()` method in Java. So, I tried using that by replacing the `if` condition and came up with a second version of code.
2. ***Code 2:***

   ```
   static int maxMoves(String s, String t) {
       int count = 0,i;

       while(true)
       {
           if(s.contains(t))
               s.replace(t,""); //Marked Statement
           else break;

           ++count;
       }

       return count;
   }
   ```

   But for some reason (I don't know why), the *"Marked Statement"* in the above code gets executed infinitely (this I noticed when I replaced the *"Marked Statement"* with `System.out.println(s.replace(t,""));`). I don't the reason for the same.

Since, I am passing only 9/14 test cases, there must be some logical error that is leading to a *"Wrong Answer"*. How do I overcome that if I use **Code 1**? And if I use **Code 2**, how do I avoid infinite execution of the *"Marked Statement"*? Or is there anyone who would like to suggest me a **Code 3**?

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: What happens, if the string is at the beginning, therefor both indexes of `substring()` are 0?

Comment: what happens if you have an empty string for either s or t given?

Comment: think of the following case, "".replace("","")? will this ever end?

Comment: Are you trying to solve [the Hackerrank challenge Reducto](https://www.hackerrank.com/contests/apc/challenges/reducto)? If so, there may be more than one string which may be removed, and because removals may create new occurrences of substrings, it is not enough to run `maxCounts` sequentially for each substring.

Comment: Can you explain? @MOehm

Comment: Consider the string "cabaaba", from which you should remove the two substrings "aa" and "bb". Remove the "aa"s, and you get "cabba". Remove the "bb"s, and you get "caa". But you're not done, because the final result should be just "c". (I haven't looked into the task in detail, but even the order in which you remove strings might be important. For example, if you have a string "aaaa", removing "aaa" fisrt will no longer enable you to remove "aa" twice in oder to reduce the string to "".)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.  In particular, post the results of *your* testing and debugging, as well as the code the produced it.

Answer (score 2):

Try saving the new (returned) string instead of ignoring it.

```
s = s.replace(t,"");
```

**replace** returns a new string; you seemed to think that it alters the given string in-place.

Comment: I am able to pass only 3/14 cases now :(

Comment: @PrakharSaxena you haven't read the challenge correctly. If it was only removing a string repeatedly the coding challenge wouldn't be that hard. It was about finding the max possible moves of removing a substring of a string. If you start left you could've got a different amount of substring then when you've started on the right

Answer (score 0):

Try adding some simple parameter checks of the strings. The strings shouldn't be equal to null and they should have a length greater than 0 to allow for counts greater than 0.

```
static int maxMoves(String s, String t) {
    int count = 0,i;

    if(s == null || s.length() == 0 || t == null || t.length() == 0)
        return 0;

    while(true)
    {
        if(s.contains(t) && !s.equals(""))
            s = s.replace(t,""); //Marked Statement
        else break;

        ++count;
    }

    return count;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You might be **missing on the edge cases** in the code 1.
In code 2, **you are not storing the new string formed** after the replace function.
The replace function replaces each substring of this string that matches the literal target sequence with the specified literal replacement sequence.

Try this out:

```
public static int findCount(String s, String t){

    if( null == s || "" == s || null == t || "" == t)
        return 0;
    int count =0;
    while(true){
        if(s.contains(t)){
            count++;
            int i = s.indexOf(t);
            s = s.substring(0, i)+s.substring(i+t.length(), s.length());
            // s = s.replace(t,"");
        }
        else
            break;
    }

    return count;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   String r1="ramraviraravivimravi";
   String r2="ravi";
    int count=0,i;
    while(r1.contains(r2))
    {
        count++;
        i=r1.indexOf(r2);
        StringBuilder s1=new StringBuilder(r1);
        s1.delete(i,i+r2.length());
        System.out.println(s1.toString());
        r1=s1.toString();
    }
```

System.out.println(count);

Answer (score 0):

First of all no logical difference in both the codes.

All the mentioned answers are to rectify the error of code 2 but none told how to pass all (14/14) cases.
Here I am mentioning a test case where your code will fail.

s = "abcabcabab";
t = "abcab"

Your answer 1
Expected answer 2

According to your code:
In 1st step, removig t from index 0 of s,
s will reduce to "cabab", so the count will be 1 only.

But actual answer should be 2
I first step, remove t from index 3 of s,
s will reduced to "abcab", count = 1.

In 2nd step removing t from index 0,
s will reduced to "", count = 2.

So answer would be 2.

If anyone know how to handle such cases, please let me know.