# Repeatedly removing a substring from a string

Tags: java, string, recursion, substring

**Problem:** Remove the substring `t` from a string `s`, repeatedly and print the number of steps involved to do the same.

**Example:** `t = ab`, `s = aabb`. In the first step, we check if `t` is contained within `s`. Here, t is contained in the middle i.e. `a(ab)b`. So, we will remove it and the resultant will be `ab` and increment the  count value by `1`. We again check if `t` is contained within `s`. Now, `t` is equal to `s` i.e. `(ab)`. So, we remove that from `s` and increment the  count. So, since `t` is no more contained in `s`, we stop and print the  count value, which is `2` in this case.

I tried to solve this using recursion

```
static int maxMoves(String s, String t) {
    if ( null == s || "" == s || null == t || "" == t){
           return 0;
    }
    int i = s.indexOf(t);
        if(i != -1) {
            return maxMoves(s.substring(0, i)+ s.substring(i+t.length(),                            s.length()), t) + 1;
        } else {
            return 0;
        }

    }
```

But I am only passing 9/14 test cases. I also tried this,

```
static int maxMoves(String s, String t) {
    int count = 0,i;

    while(true)
    {
        if(s.contains(t))
        {
            i = s.indexOf(t);
            s = s.substring(0,i) + s.substring(i + t.length());
        }
        else break;

        ++count;
    }

    return count;
}
```

But that also only passed 9/14 cases.

Could anyone help me figure out which cases I am not covering?

Comment: why not use [String#replace](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace(java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence))

Comment: `"" == s` -> [How do I compare strings in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java), or in this case `s.isEmpty()` is clearer.

Comment: Yeah, I changed it but still only 9/14 cases are being passed. I don't think empty strings are being checked for.

Answer (score 4):

Simply you can use `String::replaceFirst` with a `while` loop for example:

```
String s = "aabb";
String t = "ab";
int count = 0;
while (s.contains(t)) {
    s = s.replaceFirst(Pattern.quote(t), "");
    count++;
}

System.out.println(count);
```

Comment: I end up only passing 3/14 test cases with this unfortunately.

Comment: @AbdullahKhan try using `replaceFirst` instead of just `replace`

Comment: What if `t` contains special regex characters?

Comment: thank you @KlitosKyriacou good point in this case we can use `Pattern.quote(t)` to escape this special regex characters

Comment: Good, now it works correctly (I think). But I quite like the way Frank Underwood has got around the issue with String.replace().

Comment: I tried replace first and used Pattern.quote(t), but it isn't passing more than 9 test cases still.

Comment: @AbdullahKhan maybe the answer is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46161057/removing-a-substring-from-a-string-repeatedly#comment79299918_46161057)?

Comment: @KlitosKyriacou I checked that thread, but none of the answers were right either. I'm failing the same test cases each time, so I'm not sure what part of the problem I'm not doing

Comment: can you share the test @AbdullahKhan what test you try to solve?

Comment: I do not know what tests the program is using to test my code, this would be much easier if I did. I've ruled out any null or empty code, and I've been testing for duplicates. So I am not sure what else is left, or why none of my solutions, or other people's have been working. This is all taking place on HackerRank.

Comment: This is the best answer I believe, I just need to account for edge cases such as having a space in the inputs. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2):

Use [`String#replace`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace(char,%20char))

```
String s = "aabb";
String oldstr = s;
String x = "ab";
while(s.contains(x)){
    s = s.replace(x, "");
}
System.out.println((oldstr.length()-s.length())/x.length());
```

Comment: If I were to put the replacement in a loop, as I am trying to return a count of how many times the string is being replaced, would I take what's in the Sysout and put it into a while loop? Something like, while((oldstr.length()-s.length())/x.length()) != 0) { count++; } Or is that completely off base.

Comment: @AbdullahKhan I really don't know what you're trying to say. just put `(oldstr.length()-s.length())/x.length()` in a variable. That's the final count.

Comment: Oh you're right, I misread what you put. Your solution only passes 3/14 test cases unfortunately

Comment: @AbdullahKhan there must be some edge cases. Consider them. The code is fine

Answer (score 1):

An easy and efficient way is to accumulate the string character-by-character in a `StringBuilder`; if at any time its buffer ends with the string you want to replace, remove it:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
int c = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); ++i) {
  sb.append(s.charAt(i));
  int last = sb.length()-t.length();
  if (last >= 0 && sb.indexOf(t, last) == last) {
    sb.setLength(last);
    ++c;
  }
}
// c is now the number of times you removed t from s.
```